# Как решить Errno 111

Tags: python, поиск-библиотек

Помогите, пожалуйста: какие есть способы решения этой ошибки?

Код сервера:

```
import socket
import time
import threading

name = []

def pol():
    while True:
        try:
            user, adress = server.accept()
            print("подключился",adress)
            user.setblocking(0)
            player.append(user)
            print(user)
        except:
            pass
   
def polu():
    while True:
        for x in player:
            try:
                msg = x.recv(1024)
                print(msg)
                msg = msg.decode()
                print(msg)
                sen(msg=msg, ot=x)
            except:
                pass

def sen(msg, ot):
    for x in player:
        if not x == ot:
            x.sendall(msg.encode())
        else:
            pass




server =  socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_TCP, socket.TCP_NODELAY,1)
host = socket.gethostbyname("192.168.0.29")
port = 50005
server.bind((host, port))
server.setblocking(0)
server.listen(10)
player = []
print("сервер активен")

v = threading.Thread(target=polu)
v.start()
t = threading.Thread(target=pol)
t.start()
print("localhost")
while True:
    n = input()
    if n == "q":
        print("сервер выключен")
        server.close()
        input()
        exit()
    for y in player:
        try:
            y.sendall(n.encode())
        except:
            player.remove(y)
            y.close()
        print(y)
    time.sleep(1)
```

Код клиента:

```
import socket
import threading
def prov():
    while True:
        msg = client.recv(1024)
        msg = msg.decode()
        print(msg)

client =  socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client.connect(("62.217.189.249",50005))
try:
    client.connect_ex(("62.217.189.249",50005))
    print("всё ок")
except:
    print("сервер выключен")
    input()
    exit()
    input()
p = threading.Thread(target=prov)
p.start()
```

**Ошибка:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/Danya998pop/test.py", line 10, in <module>
    client.connect(("62.217.189.249",50005))
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

Я пытаюсь сделать простой чат для меня и друзей в разных городах, посмотрел гайды, сделал точь-в-точь как в них показано, но ничего не работает.

Comment: В первый раз слышу про cocket. Есть стандартная библиотека socket (для работы с "голыми" сокетами). Есть более высокоуровневые библиотеки, например requests (для отправки http запросов). Уточните, что именно вам нужно.

Comment: просто опечатался

Comment: Тогда чем не устраивает socket?

Comment: @insolor Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/Danya998pop/test.py", line 10, in <module>
    client.connect(("62.217.189.249",50005))
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused

Comment: Это не проблема с библиотекой, это указанный сервер отказал в подключении.

Comment: @insolor тогда можете помочь пожалуйста?

Comment: @insolor я расскажу всё что попросите только помогите пожалуйста

Comment: Приведите код,  и полный стек ошибки **прямо в вопросе**.

Comment: Все привёл @чистов_n

Comment: Вы уверены, что сервер запускается именно на IP 62.217.189.249?

Comment: Ну да это мой внешний ip

Comment: Внешний ip - это ip вашего роутера, а не компьютера, где вы запускаете сервер. Чтобы работало, нужно на роутере настроить проброс порта.

Comment: @insolor В каком смысле?   И как это зделать?

Comment: В поисковике вводите модель вашего роутера и "проброс порта". Дальше на роутере настраиваете проброс внешнего порта на локальный ip вашего компьютера на нужный порт.